# Advice on Rust TCP Server

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a TCP server with multiple clients that will resend one message from one client to another, but I'm stuck. When I send a message from a client, the server receives it, but the others don't unless they send something to the server. Threadpool is from rust book.

### Client code

#### Client module

```
const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 1024;

pub struct Client {
    write_stream: TcpStream,
    read_stream: TcpStream,
    pool: ThreadPool,
}

impl Client {
    pub fn new(config: Config) -> Self {
        let stream = TcpStream::connect(config.build_socket()).unwrap();
        Client {
            write_stream: stream.try_clone().unwrap(),
            read_stream: stream.try_clone().unwrap(),
            pool: ThreadPool::build(2),
        }
    }

    pub fn read_from_server(&self) {
        let mut buffer = [0; BUFFER_SIZE];
        let mut stream = self.read_stream.try_clone().unwrap();
        self.pool.execute(move || loop {
            match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
                Ok(n) => {
                    if n == 0 {
                        break;
                    }
                    let message = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..n]).to_string();
                    println!("Message from: {}", message);
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Error while reading message: {}", e);
                    break;
                }
            };
        });
    }

    pub fn write_to_server(&self) -> Sender<String> {
        let mut stream = self.write_stream.try_clone().unwrap();
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>();

        self.pool.execute(move || loop {
            let message = rx.recv().unwrap();
            if let Err(e) = stream.write(message.as_bytes()) {
                eprintln!("Error while sending message: {}", e);
            }
        });

        tx
    }
}
```

#### Client main:

```
fn main() {
    let config = Config::build(env::args());
    let client = Client::new(config);

    client.read_from_server();

    let tx = client.write_to_server();

    loop {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        tx.send(buffer).unwrap();
    }
}
```

### Server code

#### Server module

```
pub struct Server {
    pub listener: TcpListener,
    pub pool: ThreadPool,
    pub clients_count: usize,
    pub clients_sender: Arc<Mutex<Vec<(usize, Sender<String>)>>>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new(config: Config) -> Self {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(config.build_socket()).unwrap();

        println!(
            "Creating server on address {} and port {}",
            config.ip_address, config.port
        );

        Server {
            listener,
            pool: ThreadPool::build(config.number_of_threads),
            clients_count: 0,
            clients_sender: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())),
        }
    }

    pub fn listen(&mut self) {
        let mut id: usize = 0;

        for stream in self.listener.incoming() {
            match stream {
                Ok(s) => {
                    println!("{:?}", s.peer_addr());
                    let mut client = Client::new(s, id);
                    self.clients_count += 1;
                    let clients_sender = Arc::clone(&self.clients_sender);

                    self.pool.execute(move || {
                        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>();
                        let clone_senders = Arc::clone(&clients_sender);
                        clone_senders.lock().unwrap().push((id, tx.clone()));
                        client.handle_client(rx, clone_senders);
                    });

                    id += 1;
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    eprintln!("Error while parsing incoming stream");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Client module

```
const SIZE_OF_BUFFER: usize = 1024;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Client {
    pub stream: TcpStream,
    pub id: usize,
}

impl Client {
    pub fn new(stream: TcpStream, id: usize) -> Self {
        Client { stream, id }
    }

    pub fn handle_client(
        &mut self,
        rx: Receiver<String>,
        client_sender: Arc<Mutex<Vec<(usize, Sender<String>)>>>,
    ) {
        loop {
            let mut buffer = [0; SIZE_OF_BUFFER];
            let result = self.stream.read(&mut buffer);
            match result {
                Ok(_) => {
                    let message = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer).to_string();
                    let header = format!("<Client:{}>: ", self.id);
                    let payload = format!("{}{}", header, message);
                    println!("Message from client<{}>: {}", self.id, message);

                    client_sender
                        .lock()
                        .unwrap()
                        .iter()
                        .filter_map(|(id, tx)| {
                            if *id != self.id {
                                Some(Arc::new(tx.clone()))
                            } else {
                                None
                            }
                        })
                        .for_each(|tx| {
                            tx.send(payload.clone()).unwrap();
                        });
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    eprintln!("Error while reading from stream");
                    break;
                }
            }

            let mut write_stream = self.stream.try_clone().unwrap();

            for message in rx.try_iter() {
                write_stream.write_all(message.as_bytes()).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Server main

```
fn main() {
    let config = Config::build(env::args());
    let mut server: Server = Server::new(config);

    server.listen();
}
```

I tried to solve this problem, but unfortunately I do not know what is wrong. Could someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: Why are you using a thread pool instead of just spawning threads?

Comment: You need to use `write_all()` instead of `write()`. Also you clone the stream unnecessarily many times.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes, you are right, using threadpool is not necessary, but still when I changed `write()` to `write_to()` the client has to send something first to receive a message from another sender.

Answer (score 1):

In `handle_client()`, you handle all requests from a client in an infinite loop, but you never get to the place in the code where you receive messages from other clients and send them.

You need to either (1) spawn two threads for each client, or (2) send directly to the client's stream when received a message from it, instead of using channels.

You also need to use `iter()` from the channel and not `try_iter()`.